# Interpret character as sign

Tags: gnuplot

I have some CSV data that has numeric data with a character that indicates sign:

```
...,123H,...
...,200H,...
...,150S,...
```

Is it possible to direct GNUPlot to interpret the H and S as positive and negative signs? In other words, the above data should be plotted as

```
...,123,...
...,200,...
...,-150,...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gnuplot has very limited capacities to parse string. However, in your case you can define a function which operates on the string values of the respective columns and does the interpretation of the H and S:

```
v(s) = s[*:strlen(s)-1] * (s[strlen(s):-1] eq 'S' ? -1 : 1)
plot 'file.txt' using 1:(v(strcol(2)))
```